# How I can uninstall the plugin ez-on-da-ice from IDE Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, plugins, ide

I just want to test the `plugin` but now I need to uninstall `netbeans` IDE  to remove this plugin? Now  I really can't see the image on the screen! It´s hard!What I should to do without uninstall of the IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Menu -> Tools (Alt-T)  -> Plugins (G)
2. Select "Installed" (one left of rightmost tab) Tab
3. Click the Show Details Checkbox
4. Type ez-on-da-ice in search textbox.
5. Select ez-on-da-ice in list.
6. Click the Uninstall Button (rightmost button directly under the list)
7. Click the Uninstall Button in the Dialog
8. Finish, netbeans will restart.

If you can't see things well enough to follow these instructions, you could try adjusting your monitor settings first.

You can also delete your Netbeans user configuration directory to get back to default settings. (see http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir)

Comment: Thank you !! @WillShackeford